# Bootstrap application wizard content disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wizard

I'm using https://github.com/amoffat/bootstrap-application-wizard/ to create a application wizard.

I want to open a wizard based on which button is pressed.
So, i have used the following code:

```
$(".button").on('click',function(){
var id= $(this).data('btnid');
$("#wizard"+id).wizard().show();
});
```

But when I click on button -> close modal -> reopen the modal, the wizard content disappears, it just shows an empty wizard.

Comment: That's because the plugin is trying to create a new wizard and show it, you should keep a reference of the already created wizards and open them when the appropriate button is clicked

Comment: @koala_dev  thanks. can you please advice how i can do that?

Comment: @koala_dev  I have multiple multiple buttons with multiple wizards and the wizards are dynamic , please see code in question, i think you will understand that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be resolved by storing the references somewhere and using the reference to call show() method of the wizard.

Comment: So were you able to solve this by yourself? If so please add some sample code so the answer is more useful to future visitors