# Application Wizard not showing the card's content for second time?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am using bootstrap application wizard. When I load the wizard for second time the card is not getting initialized and content is getting disappeared.. Below is my code. I am using bootstrap 3.3.5 and Jquery 2.1.4 min version.

In controller

```
var wizard = $('#some-wizard').wizard({});
    $.fn.wizard.logging = true;
    $event.preventDefault();

    wizard.show();
    wizard.on("submit", function(wizard){
        $scope.agent = [];
        console.log("Inside submit");
        //console.log($scope.monitor);
        $scope.agent.agentId = id;
        $scope.agent.title = $("#title").val();
        $scope.agent.desc = $("#description").val();
        $scope.agent.userIds =  $rootScope.tselected;


        homeService.updateAgent($scope.agent).then(function(response) {
            if(response.sucess == 'true'){
                alert("success");
            }
            else {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        });
        wizard.submitSuccess();
                wizard.hideButtons();
                wizard.updateProgressBar(0); 
    });

    console.log("Monitor edited" + id);

    wizard.on('closed', function() {
                $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                wizard.setActiveCard('card1');
            });

    wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .im-done").click(function() {
        wizard.reset();

        wizard.hide();
    });

    wizard.el.find(".wizard-success .create-another-server").click(function() {
        wizard.reset();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I found this also: [Bootstrap application wizard content dissapears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739676/bootstrap-application-wizard-content-dissapears) , but it still left me a little confused.

After tinkering with the API a little more, I was able to fix this using a reference that the previous link discussed.

```
            //Initialize Wizard
            var wizard = $("#environment-add-template").wizard(options);


            //If the page is not refreshed, this maintains the reference for multiple environment adds
            if (wizard._cards.length != 0) {
                wizardReference(wizard);
            } else {
                wizard = wizardReference();
            }
```

I'm using knockout.js, so wizardReference(wizard) is the same as wizardReference = wizard. Also, whenever the user presses the event button to start the wizard, the wizard._cards.length will be equal to however many cards you have on the html page. If the user doesn't refresh the page, the wizard will initialize again, but the length will now be zero. The reference just initializes the wizard back to the original amount of cards.

This will bring back the original with the values. If you want to reset the values, you will have to add something like this:

```
//When the user submits the data or closes the wizard, this reverts all values to original state
            wizard.on("reset", function () {
                wizard.modal.find(':input').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                wizard.modal.find(':select').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
                wizard.modal.find(':textarea').val('').removeAttr('disabled');
            });
```

Just add wizard.reset() to a close event.